# How to capture calls to function of mocked module

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a function I want to test where I'm using Jest to mock the functions of an external module.
I want to perform an assertion on the arguments passed to the function of that mocked module.

TypeScript file to test:

```
import { update, get } from '@/dao/playerRankingDao';

const processPlayerResult = async (): Promise<void> => {

        playerRanking = await get(playerRanking, dataMapper);

        // business logic 

        await update(updatedPlayerRanking, dataMapper);
 
};
```

In the unit test I want to capture the updatedPlayerRanking argument passed to `update`.

Test file:

```
    let updateMock = jest.fn();
    jest.mock('@/dao/playerRankingDao', () => {
        return {
            get: jest.fn(),
            update: updateMock

        }
    });
    
   it ('test', () => {
      expect(updateMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ })
  });
```

I tried something like this in my test, but because Jest will automatically hoist `jest.mock` calls to the top of the module, that didn't work.

Is there a way to disable this hoisting, or another way to do this?

Comment: Just do `jest.mock('...')` then `import { update } from '...'` in the tests to get access to the test double. If the mock calls don't get hoisted then the module isn't mocked when the real implementation imports it.