# Jest: toHaveBeenCalled not detecting calls

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Following on from [How to capture calls to function of mocked module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76351692/how-to-capture-calls-to-function-of-mocked-module?noredirect=1#comment134636784_76351692) where I'm testing the function bellow

```
import { update, get } from '@/dao/playerRankingDao';

const processPlayerResult = async (): Promise<void> => {

        playerRanking = await get(playerRanking, dataMapper);

        // business logic 

        await update(updatedPlayerRanking, dataMapper);
 
};
```

Test written

```
import { update, get } from '@/dao/playerRankingDao';
jest.mock('@/dao/getPlayerRankingDao');

describe('should process insert player result', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });

    it('should update existing player result record', () => {
        const mockedGet = <jest.Mock<typeof get>>get;
        mockedGet.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(createPlayerRanking('Roger F',10000)));

        processPlayerResult();
        expect(mockedGet).toHaveBeenCalled();

        expect(mockedUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The first assertion `expect(mockedGet).toHaveBeenCalled()` works but the second one `expect(mockedUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled()` doesn't, even though `await update(updatedPlayerRanking, dataMapper);` does execute without error

```
  ● should process insert player result › should update existing player result record

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

What could I be missing

Weirdly enough when I remove the get mock (as well as the underlying logic), `toHaveBeenCalled` works on the update mock.

Comment: should it not be await processPlayerResult();? in your jest test function